# Hiding API Keys in AngularJS and NodeJS and pushing to Git and Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, heroku, api-key

I'm using API keys in both my AngularJS and NodeJS files, with the end goal of pushing my application files to Git and Heroku. However, I do not want these keys to be public. How do I go about hiding these keys? I've heard people saying to put them in a hidden file on the server side and never on the client side. If that's the case, how can I access an API key that I store on the server side from client side Javascript?

Also, when I push my files to Git and Heroku, do I just simply put those hidden files in .gitignore so that they're only my local system, or are there other ways to approach this? What's the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

your best bet here is to write a couple of local triggers that

pre-push: remove/blank out keys
post-push: put them back in

otherwise what you want isn't really part of git's area of interest

[READ MORE](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Answer (score -1):

#### If you wish to deploy from your local machine:

commit any data to your repo (fake of course, or don't commit any at all).

Now use the `assume-unchanged` flag  and mark the file as unchanged and it will not be tracked.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index

#### --[no-]assume-unchanged

> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>
> Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the "assume unchanged" bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index. If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git. This is sometimes helpful when working with a big project on a filesystem that has very slow lstat(2) system call (e.g. cifs).
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

[image]